# Building sparse COO matrix structure from Cartesian product of indices

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

**Problem**

Consider

```
P: A (N, n_x) matrix.
```

Then I want to find the indices of a sparse COO matrix such that

```
indices = []
for i in range(N):
    for j1 in range(n_x):
        for j2 in range(n_x):
            indices.append([P[i, j1], P[i, j2]])

indices = unique(indices, axis=0)
```

**Faster Solution**

The above solution is both inefficient in terms of time and memory. A faster option using Numpy is below

```
col_idx = np.reshape(np.tile(P, n_x), [N, n_x, n_x]) 
row_idx = np.transpose(col_idx, [0,2,1])
indices = np.concatenate((row_idx[:,None], col_idx[:, None]), axis=1)
indices = np.unique(indices, axis=0)
```

Note however that this still requires building 2 `N*n_x*n_x` arrays which can be much larger than necessary if we only have a small number of unique elements.

**Question**

How can I build a fast but also memory efficient algorithm for doing the following. Currently the fast solution is not usable as it requires too much memory.

The solution could be Python but also an algorithm that I could code in C would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think both in C++ and Python the way to go is using a set.

In the version below I used Numba which gives apox. 30x speedup to the pure Python version.

**Python**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time

N=500
n_x=600

P=np.random.randint(0,50,N*n_x).reshape(N,n_x)

@nb.jit()
def nb_sparse_coo(P):
  indices = set()
  for i in range(P.shape[0]):
      for j1 in range(P.shape[1]):
          for j2 in range(j1,P.shape[1]):
              indices.add((P[i, j1], P[i, j2]))
  return np.array(list(indices))

indices=nb_sparse_coo(P)
```